# Ubuntu services configuration

Tags: 14.04, server, services

Have a little problem.

I try to run Ghost platform on VPS via service.

I wrote service configuration file and put it to

/etc/init/

the content of file:

```
#/etc/init/ghost.conf

description "Ghost: Just a blogging platform"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
setuid ghost
setgid ghost
env NODE_ENV=production

chdir /var/www/ghost

exec /usr/bin/npm start --production

pre-stop exec /usr/bin/npm stop --production
```

Problem is that i run service

but it still stopped

```
root@ghost-512mb-nyc1-01:/# sudo service ghost status
ghost stop/waiting
root@ghost-512mb-nyc1-01:/# sudo service ghost start
ghost start/running, process 32581
root@ghost-512mb-nyc1-01:/# sudo service ghost status
ghost stop/waiting
root@ghost-512mb-nyc1-01:/#
```

Please, help me somebody.